# Make a Swift (2.1) enum conform to AnyObject

Tags: swift, enums, swift2

I’ve got a few dictionaries that are of types:

```
public typealias RESTPostDictionary = [RESTPostDictionaryKey : AnyObject]
public typealias RESTRequestDictionary = [RESTRequestDictionaryKey : AnyObject]
```

I’m using enums because I want the key of the dictionary to only be one of the cases in the enum:

```
public enum RESTPostDictionaryKey : String
{
    case Requests = "requests"
}
```

And:

```
public enum RESTRequestDictionaryKey : String
{
    case RequestURI = "request_uri"
    case HTTPMethod = "http_method"
    case DataDictionary = "data_dictionary"
    case RequestIdentifier = "request_identifier"
    case ResponseFormats = "response_formats"
}
```

Since my enum is technically a `String` type, I’d have thought this would be no problem for the compiler to get its underlying string value (which does conform to `AnyObject`) and use that. But I get the warning:

`Cannot assign value of type ‘Array<RESTRequestDictionary>’ aka … to type 'AnyObject?’`

in the following function:

```
class public func postDictionaryWithRequestDictionaries(requestDictionaries: Array<RESTRequestDictionary>) -> RESTPostDictionary
{
    var postDictionary = RESTPostDictionary()

    postDictionary[.Requests] = requestDictionaries

    return postDictionary
}
```

Is there any way of telling the compiler to get its `String` through the use of a protocol or something else without having to rely on the dirty and un-Swift-like .rawValue?

Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you restricting the dictionary to only contain objects? If you don't need only objects, you can just change `AnyObject` to `Any`

Comment: I didn’t know about `Any`, but when I do use `Any`, I then cannot use the dictionary as a dictionary, for example I use the method `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postDictionary, options: [])` and get the error that `’RESTPostDictionary’ does not conform to expected type ‘AnyObject’`

Comment: Oh yeah in that case you have to use objects, Obj-C can't handle anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
public typealias RESTPostDictionary = [RESTPostDictionaryKey : AnyObject]
```

What you mean is this:

```
public typealias RESTPostDictionary = [String : AnyObject]
```

The enum is not the string. But it is the string that you intend to use as the key.

When you use the enum case as the key, take its `rawValue`:

```
postDictionary[RESTRequestDictionaryKey.Requests.rawValue] = requestDictionaries
```

Thus, for example, this is legal:

```
enum Keys : String {
    case Key1 = "hey"
    case Key2 = "ho"
    case Key3 = "hey nonny no"
}

var d = [String:AnyObject]()
d[Keys.Key1.rawValue] = 1
d[Keys.Key2.rawValue] = 2
```

Comment: I understand your point, but I’d like my `RESTPostDictionary` to only use the keys that are in the `RESTPostDictionaryKey` enum. My point is surely this should work as the enum is technically a `String` type which does conform to `AnyObject`?

Comment: You don't understand my point, actually, because my point is that the enum is _not_ technically a String. It is technically an enum, which is a very different animal.

Comment: Okay, so there’s no way of telling the compiler other than the `rawValue` property?

Comment: I’ve changed my enums back to structs that have static constants for each key. Thanks for your help though

Comment: I haven’t had a go at you anywhere, I’m thankful you helped and disappointed my idea didn’t work.

Comment: Okay you need to stop trying to offend yourself. I didn’t mark it as closed because of my workload. It’s marked as the correct answer now. Thanks.

Comment: @Adam Carter "the enum is technically a String" seems not to be true for me. enum E:String means enum with rawValue.Type == String

Answer (score 1):

```
class Box<T> {
  let value: T
  init(value: T) {
    self.value = value
  }
}
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("foo", object: Box(value: YourOwnStruct())) // OK
```

You can cast your struct/enum directory if implement AnyObjectConvertible at that type.

```
extension YourOwnStruct: AnyObjectConvertible {}

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("foo", object: YourOwnStruct()) // OK let value = notification.object as? YourOwnStruct
```

View complete answer/download source from [here](https://github.com/tarunon/AnyObjectConvertible)

Answer (score 0):

why not simple use enum as key?

```
import Foundation

enum E:String, CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return self.rawValue }
    case A = "text A"
    case B = "B text"
    case C = "neither A nor B but C"
}

var dict: Dictionary<E, Any> = [:]
dict[E.A] = "alfa"
dict[E.B] = 1
dict[E.C] = NSDate()

dump(dict)

/*
▿ 3 key/value pairs
▿ [0]: (2 elements)
- .0: E.C
- .1: Nov 8, 2015, 11:01 AM
▿ [1]: (2 elements)
- .0: E.A
- .1: alfa
▿ [2]: (2 elements)
- .0: E.B
- .1: 1
*/

print(dict)
// [neither A nor B but C: 2015-11-08 10:02:47 +0000, text A: "alfa", B text: 1]
```

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
>
> All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,
>   NSDictionary, or NSNull.
>
> All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
>
> Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

```
import Foundation

enum E:String, CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return self.rawValue }
    case A = "key A"
    case B = "key B"
    case C = "key C"
}

var dict: Dictionary<NSString, AnyObject> = [:]

dict[E.A.description] = "alfa"
dict[E.B.description] = [1,2,3]
dict[E.C.description] = NSDate()

dict is AnyObject // false
let nsdict = dict as NSDictionary
nsdict is AnyObject // true
print(nsdict)

/*

{
    "key A" = alfa;
    "key B" =     (
        1,
        2,
        3
    );
    "key C" = "2015-11-09 23:13:31 +0000";
}
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I’m being told by the compiler that this type does not conform to `AnyObject` when using it with the `NSJSONSerialization` class

Comment: Is there a way of writing an extension to make my custom type `[StringBasedEnum : AnyObject]` conform to the Swift type of `AnyObject`?

Comment: now i see Matts answer. so, you know everything ... enum is enum, not a string. even though the key in NSDictionary is NSString, you are able to compare it whit your enums. enum with associated string value works like limited set of string values. i use enum values conforming to Streamable as my JSON 'staff'. serialization to JSON is easy and fast, i use my own parser with direct mapping to my Json compatible enums. everything depends on your needs, there is a lot of examples on the web